# How to turn off error messages in visualforce?

Tags: apex-code, visualforce

I have a VisualForce page that has three functionalities,
Hence it has three 'public PageReference' subroutines,
That are called when an action happens in the page [i.e. button]

One of the functionalities requires user input [i.e. inputText],
So the main APEX code has a variable declaration for that input:

```
public String UserInput { get; set; }
```

Since each task is not really related,
When I hit the button on the other two functionalities,
I get a VisualForce error, 
Because the inputText object has no user input,

How can I prevent that from happening,

Another way to solve this,
How do I turn off VisualForce Error messages?
So I can do error handling from APEX,
Looking at the debug log file,
The error is in VisualForce NOT APEX,

Thanks

Comment: I see no "hat" here, it is some other type of epitaxtually activated gazonta?

Comment: Sorry, not sure what that means!!!

Comment: "prevent hat from happening" - it's a joke on your typo :) preventing hats from happening...lol

Comment: Oh ok , sorry about that, any suggestions for the question itself

Comment: Would really appreciate any programming tips

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to fire validation you can use the immediate = true attribute on the CommandButton/CommandLink to bypass any validation. - This isn't optimal in my opinion

If you only want to submit part of a page and still fire validation have a look at the ActionRegion. This should allow you to wrap a particular Region for the action call. This is probably best for your purpose.

Sorry I don't have time to post full examples but that should point you in the right direction :)

Comment: I have tried ActionRegion, but it did not work, but let me try the other solution

Comment: Ah,  immediate = "true" WORKED, great thanks. I'm handling errors inside the Apex code.